# Symfony 4: Multiple inclusion of a file

Tags: include, twig, symfony4

Here is my `base.html.twig`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% include 'flashes/page-title.html.twig' %}</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>{% include 'flashes/page-title.html.twig' %}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm wondering why twig includes only once this file ?

Comment: What result do you get? Works for me: https://twigfiddle.com/s540oy

Comment: Only one inclusion never both.
My `page-title.html.twig` contains `{% for title in app.flashes('title') %}{{ title }}{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get a flash message from the flashbag, the message gets cleared at the same time. You can see this in [Symfony's documentation of flash messages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages) as well as in the [`FlashBagInterface` API](http://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Flash/FlashBagInterface.html#method_get).

So my guess is that Twig includes the file twice, but the second time the flashbag is just empty. That's why you don't get anything for the `h1` tag. You can confirm this by putting something static (e.g. simply `Hello world`) to the `flashes/page-title.html.twig` file and see whether the file gets included twice.

You could instead use the `peek()` method to retrieve the message while keeping it in the bag, i.e. something like `{% for title in app.flashes.peek('title') %}` or `{% for title in app.session.flashbag.peek('title') %}` if the former doesn't work. But then the message wouldn't get cleared. It might or might not be a problem in your case.

Could something else than flash messages be a better approach in this case?

Comment: You are all right! Given that, `app.session.flashbag.peek('title')` seems to return an array.
I thought flash a pratical solution but until I find the best way with it, I go back to my previous logic that works!